# Laravel API no longer authenticates after server migration

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel API that is currently hosted on a GoDaddy server. GoDaddy needed to migrate this application to a smaller server, and once they did, I am able to authenticate with the API with no errors; however, when I send a subsequent request with the API token, Laravel throws an `AuthenticationException` and I get a 401 error response.

**Authentication Request**

```
POST https://example.com/api/v1/authenticate
BODY {"api_token":"lKqsFGhhMfKFtly9Y2HJOiDOr1Gnu2eERbQlsPXXjZwZb1RZ"}
```

**Authentication Response**

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": 200,
        "success": true,
        "results": 0,
        "endpoint": "https://example.com/api/v1/authenticate"
    },
    "data": {
        "player": {
            "id": 667,
            "username": "myusername",
            "email": "user@example.com",
            "is_logged_id": 1,
            "api_token": "lKqsFGhhMfKFtly9Y2HJOiDOr1Gnu2eERbQlsPXXjZwZb1RZ"
        }
    }
}
```

**Authenticated API Request**

```
curl --location 'https://example.com/api/v1/categories' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer lKqsFGhhMfKtr9f0zB4szYiFtly9Y2HJOiDOr1Gnu2eERbQlsPXXjZwZb1RZ' \
--header 'Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImQwVk5TdkYwUTFtU25qb3RLYmR3dXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMi9tUWdWUDFjK0ozQVlNMzBQTVdJUmdaT2pjOCt3akMzZ0t5Z1huUlB0ekI1Q0drYlY0WEpvWkk3MlJWcVVrTVZ0SXdwRW14NnpCb2RMTDZMV1ZGa3crMmdJbXhZeU1GUGcrN1JBMytzQitEWWlkNzNqVWVUMTVoSkw0Z1BSOGsiLCJtYWMiOiIzN2ZkNWEzMjQxNmI3MTBiNjRhN2EzOGFhZTEzN2FkOTY0OTY0NTQ3NmE4YjU1NWQ0NDE4NjAzYTg3MzYzN2E1IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D'
```

**Authenticated API Response with Headers**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#39 // app/Exceptions/Handler.php:15
  #headers: array:8 [
    "accept" => array:1 [
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "user-agent" => array:1 [
      0 => "PostmanRuntime/7.37.0"
    ]
    "cache-control" => array:1 [
      0 => "no-cache"
    ]
    "postman-token" => array:1 [
      0 => "66cf99ea-91d9-4855-8ab7-901d0c75ad90"
    ]
    "host" => array:1 [
      0 => "example.com"
    ]
    "accept-encoding" => array:1 [
      0 => "gzip, deflate, br"
    ]
    "connection" => array:1 [
      0 => "keep-alive"
    ]
    "x-https" => array:1 [
      0 => "1"
    ]
  ]
  #cacheControl: array:1 [
    "no-cache" => true
  ]
}


{
    "error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

I can't reproduce this error using a local version of the same API, so it seems server-dependent. I have even downloaded the API from the site and run it using `php artisan serve` and haven't had the same issues. I have run `composer install` and have had no errors when running it. Could there be some server-side configuration that I am missing?

Comment: Hi, Ciara! Did you check your CORS configurations? I'm guessing this might have to do with the server rejecting a connection from an unknown host or something similar. I think it's worth checking the API's session and CORS configurations (`config/session.php` and `config/cors.php`). By the way, I was able to reproduce your error via Postman.

Comment: Try `dump($request)` in the exception handler and see if it has the values you expect. You should also not post personal data in questions...

Comment: Also that `.htaccess` looks like bad news; you should have the web root of the server pointed at the `public` directory and NOT the application directory.

Comment: @miken32 it seems to be pointed at the `public` directory

Comment: @Zeke the session driver is `file`.

the CORS config is:

`<?php

return [

       'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];`

Oddly enough, that is the same in the local version. I am able to reproduce this error against the production version in Postman; I am unable to reproduce this error running the API locally.

Comment: The only `.htaccess` file should be in the public directory, and it should look like this: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/11.x/public/.htaccess

Comment: Seems unlikely to have anything to do with the .htaccess file though. [edit] your question to include the contents of the request. (e.g. `dump($request->headers, $request->getContent());`

Comment: @miken32 I have a cURL request in my question with headers, or do you mean something else? Thank you for your help!

Comment: In the exception handler you posted a part of

Comment: Why do you need to send a `XSRF-TOKEN` to an API request? APIs generally don't require a session to function and `XSRF-TOKEN` does require a session

Comment: @apokryfos that was from Postman. I am not sending a `XSRF-TOKEN` in the API request from the mobile app.

Comment: @miken32 after adding `dump($request->headers, $request->getContent());` to the Handler method, it appears that the request is null? At least, nothing is added to the logs from the line. I also have a LogRequestResponse middleware that I created, and the request is empty there as well: `[2024-03-25 17:35:56] production.INFO: {"URI":"https:\/\/example.com\/api\/v1\/categories","METHOD":"GET","REQUEST_BODY":[],"RESPONSE":"{\"error\":\"Unauthenticated.\"}"}`

Comment: Output from `dump()` would be shown in the response, before `{"error":"Unauthenticated."}` , not in your logs.

Comment: @miken32 I see, is this the correct format? `dump($request->headers, $request->getContent()); if ($request->expectsJson()) {return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401); }`

Comment: That should be it

Comment: @miken32 headers added. I don't see a header for the token, unless it was named differently. That seems odd, considering that the token is being added correctly when I run the API locally.

Comment: You show a curl request, but the User-Agent says it's Postman. Beyond that I don't know. Try actually doing the fetch with `curl` and see if it's any different? Could just be Postman is misconfigured. And you can get rid of the CSRF token, it should not be needed for API routes. (Though again, I don't see the cookie header showing in the dump of the request...)

Comment: @miken32 I was sending it through Postman because the app that calls the api throws a runtime exception when calling the API (due to the format of the dump, which is in HTML). The headers sent through the app are as follows: `{Authorization=Bearer c57b8RxWhiOqMOQeP9M3zkR0avyegG4s2jexboe0ju0PewONVWWKEQNt6gMy, Accept=application/json}`.